# A school with a roman mosaic, a painting and ghosts

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a live action show I saw either in the very late 80s or very early 90s.

It was based on a mystery in a school where a Roman mosaic was found, that one of the faces was similar to a more modern painting.

There was also ghosts in the school as well.

The show ended with a scene of loads of telephone operators taking calls from the public about what the mystery was about.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: That's the plot of Pam Keevil's *There's no such thing as Ghosts* but that's a book. https://www.amazon.com/Theres-No-Such-Thing-Ghosts/dp/1848764774